# self becomes nil even if strongify in Reactivecocoa

Tags: ios, signals, reactive-cocoa

I guess the code itself explains everything, so take a look at the code below.

```
-(RACSignal *)bossMethod {
    @weakify(self)
    return [[[self method1] flattenMap:^RACStream *(id value) {
        @strongify(self)
        return [self method2];
    }] flattenMap:^RACStream *(id value) {
        @strongify(self)
        return [self method3];
    }];
}
```

Basically, I chained signals to perform multiple methods step by step. But method 3 wasn't get called at all. So I dogged in and found that self became nil at the point where `[self method3]` was about to get call. How'd it happen? why `@strongify(self)` didn't work on this case? I'd appreciate any advices.

Comment: This is the expected behavior, `@weakify` make you weakly capture self, and `@strongify` turns the weak variable to a strong variable. So if the weak variable itself is nil, the strong variable must be nil too.

Comment: Nope I don't think so. If self itself was nil then none of method should run but method 1 and method 2 ran find but not method 3

Comment: This is totally possible if the signal returned by [self method2] lives and sends some value after the dealloc of self.

Answer (score 1):

`self` might have been set to `nil` between between execution of the first and the second `flattenMap` block (because the last `strong`reference to the object being `self` was removed).

In general `@strongify` doesn't guarantee that a variable will be non-nil. It only guarantees that it won't be suddendly set to `nil` *inside* the scope (in your case, inside the `flattenMap` block).

Let's say you haven't used `@strongify` and have a following piece of code:

```
  @weakify(self)
    return [[self method1] flattenMap:^RACStream *(id value) {
        [self doSomethingPossiblyLong];  //1
        return [self method2]; //2
    }];
```

Now inside the block passed to `flattenMap` you do two operations. The first (1) one does some (possibly long) computations. The second (2) does something that depends on the result of (1). And you deal with multi-threaded code, so during these computations (or after them) another thread can kick in.

In this second thread, the last strong reference to the object which is your `self` might be removed. For example, it might be the UI (main) thread, and it can dismiss a view controller which owns this object. Then ARC will do its job, turning all the weak references to this object to `nil`.

Now the execution gets back to the `flattenMap` block, to this line:

```
return [self method2]; //2
```

But `self` has turned into `nil`. All the previous computations were in vain, that's too bad.

In this case it makes sense to use `@strongify`. Because you want to make sure that after the code in `flattenMap`block starts executing, the reference to `self` (or other variable wrapped in the `@strongify` macro) won't be `nil` until the very end of the block.

Note that in the code you posted there are only single method calls inside `flattenMap`, so you don't really benefit from `@strongify`. But it might still be a good habit to use it, so you won't forget about it when you add more methods called on `self` inside a block.

Comment: If `@strongify(self)` can't guarantee self will be non-nil, then what's point to use @weakify and @strongify? Doing so, you have risk your code won't run . If not using @weakify and @strongify then you potentially make retained cycle.

Comment: You should definitely use `@weakify(self)` to avoid retain cycle. But `@strongify(self)` is not obligatory. Using only `@weakify(self)` is sufficient in many cases.  As I mentioned in my answer, you may want to use it, when there are multiple methods called on `self` inside one block. @strongify guarantees that if the first method was executed when`self` was not `nil` , all the other methods *in this block* will be called with non-nil `self` as well. See also discussion in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28809324/2128900